# How to measure a app's startup time from cli?

Tags: linux, time, command-line-interface

i am trying to time the startup time for apps from cli . `time app -e true` this command seems to work for some apps but for others it says `Unknown option -e` . is there a standard way of doing this which works for all the apps ?

Comment: You first need to define what "startup time" is supposed to mean. Your conclusion will probably be that this is something that can only be defined by the application itself. So no, there is no standard way of doing this. `time` measures the time until the process that you start exits.

Comment: i simply want to compare and check which application opens/loads faster ( in layman words ,eg. if i open text editors , which one loads & let me start editing faster ) . is time the wrong tool for that ?

Comment: Every application defines its own meaning for command line options. Why would `-e true` have the same meaning for different applications?

Comment: So you're only talking about GUI applications, and want to measure the time until you see something displayed? That will be dependent on what it's displaying? E.g. a web browser will depend on the URL you go to.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is no, unless you have source code and can instrument the application.

Comment: Yes correct , i am only talking about GUI applications & i want to measure the time taken until they visually appear on the screen .

Comment: Guys over on https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/782 seem to be using time command to measure the startup time , i thought its the correct way to do this

Comment: You could conceivably check the time until the window is created, but I don't think there is any standard tool for that, so you would likely have to write it yourself. Just because the window has been created also doesn't mean that the program is ready to accept user input. That is not something that can be clearly defined. E.g. one part of the window could already be responsive to user input while another is not.

Comment: @Sachin In that link not only the startup time is measured. `alacritty -e false` is running the terminal, asking it to run the `false` executable (which does nothing but exit immediately). So `time alacritty -e false` is measuring the time it takes to start the terminal, run the `false` command, and shutdown the terminal. It is measuring the whole execution time. However, they are making the assumption that shutdown time is usually not significant over startup time and that evaluation of the `false` command doesn't take any significant time.

Comment: If you have a program that has a similar option, i.e. an option to ask it to startup and then immediately shutdown again, you could use that together with `time` for a similar effect. But that relies on the program offering such an option (like e.g. `alacritty` does with `-e`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation , if you can just paste that as answer, i will accept it as solution as it's clear now that it's app dependent & can't time any app like that universally

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach using Bash; those using Zsh can probably adapt, but I am unsure how redirection and process-substitution works there...

The approach assumes your app will spit out some meaningful log/status message; we use `"Listening on port 8080"` and `"Shutdown complete!"` as start-up and shutdown markers, respectively:

```bash
START_MARKER="Listening on port 8080"

STOP_MARKER="Shutdown complete!"

(
    sleep 2
    echo "Not ready..."
    sleep 2
    echo "Not ready..."
    sleep 2
    echo "$START_MARKER"
    sleep 2
    echo "The application has not exited"
    sleep 2
    echo "It's now busy doing work"
    sleep 2
    echo "It's still busy doing work"
    sleep 2
    echo "$STOP_MARKER"
    sleep 2
    echo "Some phantom message (just for illustration)"
) | tee \
    >(time read < <(grep -q "$START_MARKER"); cat > /dev/null) \
    >(time read < <(grep -q "$STOP_MARKER" ); cat > /dev/null)
```

It should be obvious how to extend this to capture elapsed time from invocation to some other logged milestone.

Note the `cat > /dev/null`s, which are necessary to keep the pipe going; without it, `tee` will stop consuming `stdin` and the whole pipe will terminate prematurely.